# Como calcular a frequencia que os dados aparecem no django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-rest-framework

Oi, estou fazendo uma barra de pesquisa com filtros, nela o usuário pode escolher se quer ordenar pela frequência ou ordenar por outro campo(que está ordenando tudo certo), o que dá problema é quando pesquiso pela frequência, que no caso contará quantas vezes determinada comida foi cadastrada e mostrara todas mas ordenada da mais frequente para a menos frequente.

Estou tentando calcular da seguinte forma:

```
queryset = Compras.objects.values('comidas').annotate(c=Count('comidas')).order_by('c')
```

Quando eu coloco para printar no terminal lá aparece ordenado, mas quando tento acessar o servidor e fazer a pesquisa dá o erro `NoReverseMatch`. O pode está errado?

Answer (score 0):

NoReverseMatch é um erro associado ao urls.py e/ou templates do Django e não do models. É necessário informar como está configurado as urls e como você está utilizando e o código no templates responsável pela essa pesquisa/ordenação.